# Error compiling project in AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor

This is an error generated when compiling my project in AppHarbor.
Researched the restrictions of AppHarbor but could not find anything.

Today my application has the following structure:

1. Sql Server (Add-on AppHarbor)
2. Css and Javascritp minify by Bundle (Microsoft solutions)
3. 3 projetos (Web->MVC4, Data->Class library, Services->Class library)
4. Work in Medium Trust environment

Full build report:

http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/LHZBHhKnBC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use Sql Server compact ... remove those dependencies and use plain ol' ado.net